# Read data from a usb barcode scanner in Python

Tags: python, barcode-scanner, libusb, pyusb

I am using the following code to read from a usb barcode scanner in Windows.
However, it returns this error :

**raise USBError(_strerror(ret), ret, _libusb_errno[ret])
usb.core.USBError: [Errno 5] Input/Output Error**

How can I correct this code to read sent data from barcode scanner?

```
import usb.core

dev = usb.core.find(idVendor=0x05f9,idProduct=0x4005)

data = []
endpoint = dev[0][(0,0)][0]

while 1:
    data += dev.read(endpoint.bEndpointAddress, endpoint.wMaxPacketSize)
    print(data)
```

Comment: It seems that you should install the device driver and access it with PySerial. [USB-COM-CDC/ACM Barcode Scanner USB\VID_05F9&PID_4005](http://deviceinbox.com/usb/vid-05F9-pid-4005.html)

Comment: If you're trying to do something with PyUSB alone, you'll probably need to do some extra work to recognize and use your composite devices separately. [USB-COM Composite Interface](https://community.osr.com/discussion/255819/usb-com-composite-interface), [Programming with PyUSB 1.0](https://github.com/pyusb/pyusb/blob/master/docs/tutorial.rst)